# Dropbox on NFS-mounted folder

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, dropbox

I am using Dropbox on my Ubuntu box with the Dropbox folder being present on a drive mounted via an entry in /etc/fstab. I am encountering slight annoyance after each reboot. When I log in, I get presented with a message that dropbox folder is missing. However, at the time I am actually logged in, the folder is already there as the mount completed pretty soon in the boot process.

When I simply quit the prompt and then re-launch dropbox again, all is without a glitch.

So, my question is - how can I make dropbox launcher wait for all the pending /etc/fstab mounts to be complete?

The NFS mount is on the same server as is used to server the Ubuntu's virtual hdd (VMWare), so the issue of the machine booting up and the share not being there is extremely unlikely.

Comment: Have you considered starting the dropbox service after the nfs-mount service? How do you start dropbox anyway? [instructions](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-managing-services-with-update-rc-d/)

Comment: That would be great - I've simply used Dropbox, I've not looked yet at which level it gets lauched. Power of the default I suppose. What would be the easiest way to find out? I am having similar "trouble" with crashplan, however, that one re-scans by itself in 10 minutes and finds the data there.

Comment: How did you "simply use dropbox"? Ubuntu package or binary from dropbox.com? If you used a ubuntu package, I assume they (ubuntu devs) launch the dropbox background process as any other service. The instructions for giving daemons (services) priorities are in the link above. If you look at the instructions it will become obvious how to find out whether the dropbox service is launched before or after the nfs-mount service. I have little to no experience with Ubuntu, otherwise I'd give you a straight answer ...and if you used the binary provided by Dropbox.com, I have no idea.

Comment: By "simply use Dropbox" means I've installed it from the binary provided by Dropbox, which did all the setting up (and patched the file manager amont other things). I will have a look at the runlevels of nfs-mount and Dropbox and make sure that Dropbox is in a higher one. Also, what if DB is on a higher run level but the nfs-mount takes some time to mount the directory? Would I need to introduce arbitrary delay time into DB launch script?

Comment: Maybe, though those mounts should not take much longer than a ping between the server and client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you used https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86 and not the .deb package, a possible way of making the dropbox launcher wait would be with a shell script. *Actually, I think you used the .deb package since you said that it "patched the file manager". Anyway, the script below should work regardless of installation method.*

As far as I can see, `mountall(8)` is run as an "upstart job" in
Ubuntu (whatever that is). It runs untill all filesystems (including NFS) are mounted.
We can check that it is running or start it. When the **USR1** signal is received by that
process, all NFS systems are mounted. If the mounts are successful, `mountall` dies. This script must be run as the super user.

### /usr/local/bin/dropbox-wait-mount

```
#!/bin/sh
runas={$1:-root}
mpid=`pidof mountall`
if [ -z "$mpid" ] ; then
        mountall --daemon --no-events -q
        mpid=`pidof mountall`
else
        echo mountall is running, going to notify it to mount nfs shares
fi

kill -USR1 $mpid # see /etc/init/mountall-net.conf and mountall(8)
mpid=`pidof mountall`

while [ -n "$mpid" ]; do
        echo waiting for all mounts
        sleep 30
        kill -USR1 $mpid # see /etc/init/mountall-net.conf and mountall(8)
        sleep 1
        mpid=`pidof mountall`
done

echo should be safe to run dropbox now
exec su $runas -c /home/$runas/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

The man page advices not to rely on the functionality of `mountall`, but given the nature 
of *"temporary solutions"* I think you can use this for some time.

And for some integration with Ubuntu up-start jobs:

### /etc/init/dropbox.conf

```
# based on ssh.conf

description     "Dropbox daemon"
env RUNAS=root # use /etc/init/dropbox.override

#start on stopped mountall-net RESULT=ok
start on remote-filesystems
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 10 5
umask 022

# 'sshd -D' leaks stderr and confuses things in conjunction with 'console log'
console none

pre-start script
    test -x /usr/local/bin/dropbox-wait-mount || { stop; exit 0; }
end script

# if you used to set SSHD_OPTS in /etc/default/ssh, you can change the
# 'exec' line here instead
exec /usr/local/bin/dropbox-wait-mount $RUNAS || { stop; exit 0; }
```

### /etc/init/dropbox.override

```
env RUNAS=jaroslav
```

This example should run only after all network file systems have been mounted, but it can also be run manually:

```
start dropbox #RUNAS=jaroslav
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to just use autofs to mount the nfs for you, then its on demand and you dont have to worry about synchronization

here is my config

```
$ grep home  /etc/auto.master 
/home2 /etc/auto.home

$ cat /etc/auto.home

dropbox -intr,nfsv4,soft NFS.intranet:/backups/dropbox

$ echo $HOME
/home2/dropbox

$ id
uid=1001(dropbox) gid=1001(dropbox) groups=1001(dropbox)
```